# Reserve amount that will fall back at a specific time if not used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I'm developing an app in Ruby on Rails where companies buy advertising campaigns. First they buy credits to their account on my site, then they buy the campaigns with the credits. The thing is the campaign is payed per view/click. A company reserves a budget of credits for each campaign and these reserved credits can't be used to buy other campaigns with. When a campaign ends and not all credits are used they will be un-reserved and available to buy more campaigns for.

How do I structure the models in the database and how to move/reserve/un-reserve the credits in order to periodically check for any credits that should be un-reserved in a background process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the money is kept in the company's account all the time. The goal is then to dynamically calculate how much of the funds that are reserved and how much that are not. This can be done if every campaign have a `reserved amount` attribute and a `used amount` attribute. When a user clicks on the campaign I withdraw money from the companies account and add them to the campaigns `used` account.

Answer (score 1):

Have a client/campaigns relationship. Each client has a number of credits. Each client campaign can withdraw credits from the client. As a campaign is viewed/clicked it withdraws credit from the client campaign.

A process periodically checks for lapsed campaigns. When it finds one, any remaining credits are deposited back to the client's main account.

Comment: I should add to my question that my number one goal is to avoid dependencies on background processes. Otherwise this would be one solution.

Comment: Then your option would be to do the "that campaign is over" processing manually, in which case the implementation is the same except for how the process is started, or you do it on a campaign click and say "oh, looks like that campaign is over, I'll close it out". The solution is the same, the triggering mechanism is different.

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. Your solution is the same as what I just wrote in my answer. I didn't see that before I wrote my answer. If it is the same, then it is probably a good idea, as both of us thought about it.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I didn't see your answer. Yep, looks to be about the same thing--IMO it's sensible because it meets the requirements, and is probably the simplest thing that could possible work :)

Comment: what I don't understand is "[...] withdraws credit from the client campaign". Shouldn't it be "[...] withdraws credit from the client"?

Comment: Not in my system, no--since credit is transferred from the client to the campaign, I'm tracking it there. The way I understood the req, a client could have multiple campaigns. A campaign would end if the campaign itself ran out of credit, which is different than the client running out of credit.